Is there an Oracle Model Clause equivalent in Snowflake?
I am looking for a way to use an Oracle Model Clause in Snowflake SQL.
Here is my Oracle SQL Model Clause:
FROM INPUTS 
    MODEL 
        PARTITION BY (ITEM, PLANT)
        DIMENSION BY (DAYSOUT) MEASURES (
            TRANSACTIONDATE, "SCHEDULEDPICKTIME", 
            "ACTUAL PROMISED PICK DATE", "PRODUCTIONDATE", 
            "PRODUCTIONPLANNUMBER", "WORK ORDER NUMBER", 
            "INTERCOSALESORDERNUMBER", "INTERCOPURCHASEORDERNUMBER", 
            "SALESORDERNUMBER", "SOLD TO NO", 
            "SHIP TO NO", "LOAD PLAN NUMBER", 
            "LAST STATUS", "PURCHASEORDERNUMBER", 
            "QLEADTIME", "TRANSACTIONTYPE", 
            "INV QTY AVAILABLE", "INV QTY INTRANSIT", 
            "INTERCO QTY ON PO", "INV QTY IN QUARANTINE", 
            "PAST DUE INV QTY IN QUARANTINE", 
            "INV QTY ON HOLD", "QTY ON WO", 
            "QTY ON WR", "PAST DUE QTY ON WO", 
            "QTY ARRIVING VIA INTERCO SHIPMENT", 
            "QTY ON SALES ORDER", "PAST DUE QTY ON SALES ORDER", 
            "QTY ON INTERCO SALES ORDER", "INTERCOFLAG", 
            "AVG WKLY SHIPMENTS OVER 6WK", 
            "AVG WKLY SHIPMENTS OVER 1QTR", 
            "AVG WKLY SHIPMENTS OVER 6MTH", 
            "AVG WKLY SHIPMENTS 1YR", "ORIGINAL ORDER", 
            "ORIGINAL PRODUCTION REQUEST", 
            SUPPLY, DEMAND, 0 BEGINNINGINVENTORY, 
            0 ENDINGINVENTORY, 0 PREDICTEDSHORT
        ) RULES 
        UPDATE 
            ITERATE(1000000) UNTIL (PREVIOUS(BEGINNINGINVENTORY[ITERATION_NUMBER + 1]) IS NULL) (
                BEGINNINGINVENTORY[ITERATION_NUMBER] = GREATEST(0, NVL(SUPPLY[CV()- 1], 0) + NVL(DEMAND[CV()- 1], 0) + NVL(BEGINNINGINVENTORY[CV()- 1], 0)), 
                ENDINGINVENTORY[ITERATION_NUMBER] = GREATEST(0, NVL(SUPPLY[CV()], 0) + NVL(DEMAND[CV()], 0) + NVL(ENDINGINVENTORY[CV()- 1], 0)), 
                PREDICTEDSHORT[ITERATION_NUMBER] = LEAST(0, NVL(DEMAND[CV()],0) + NVL(BEGINNINGINVENTORY[CV()], 0))
            ) 
ORDER BY 
  ITEM, 
  PLANT, 
  DAYSOUT


I believe you can get what you need without ITERATE in the model. In other words you do not need to use ITERATE to loop over all records for each item. The alternative in snowflake might be recursive CTE.

MODEL clause doesn't exist in any other sql dialect. It is Oracle specific.
To do the job as with Oracle MODEL clause
you will need to use one or more other techniques such as:

recursive CTEs,
CTEs,
nested subqueries,
window functions,
pivot,
unpivot,
user defined functions

